# C#: Getting Error in detecting Login-Password of Employee

Tags: c#

It shows same message"Username and password is correct" for each password and username i enter, Please help me detect Incorrect password.

```
      private void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {  
        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command= new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection=connection;
        command.CommandText="Select * from EmployeeData where Username ='"+txt_Username.Text+"' and Password='"+ txt_Password.Text+"'";
        OleDbDataReader reader= command.ExecuteReader();
        int count=0;
        while(reader.Read());
        {
            count =count+1;
        }

        if (count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username and password is correct");
        }

        else if(count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username or password is NOT correct");
        }
        connection.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in line    `while(reader.Read());`
remove

> ;

from end

`while(reader.Read())
        {
            count =count+1;
        }` is true

Answer (score 0):

Your password recognition is just looking if there is exactly one data-set. The function `reader.Read()` reads the next data-set. 
You count how often `Read` is able to read in the next data set. Then you base your decision about the validity of the password on that number.

That probaly wasn't your idea.